# Jest Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

Using Jest on my Reactjs project , which has jsx file for component now I am facing this error upon loading setup files from jest.config.js

[image]

**Jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
// Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
clearMocks: true,

// An array of glob patterns indicating a set of files for which coverage information should be collected
//  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}'],

collectCoverageFrom: ['./components/**/**.{jsx}'],

// The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
coverageDirectory: 'coverage',

// An array of file extensions your modules use
moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx'],

// The paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment before each test
setupFiles: ['./setupTests.js'],

// The test environment that will be used for testing
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',

// The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
 // testMatch: ["***/Components/Views/**/*.js?(x)", "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"],


  testMatch: ["***/Components/Views/HouseKeeping/T_Form/*.js?(x)", "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"],

 // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
   testPathIgnorePatterns: ['\\\\node_modules\\\\'],

   // This option sets the URL for the jsdom environment. It is reflected in properties such as location.href
 //  testURL: 'http://localhost',

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths, matched files will skip transformation
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],

// Indicates whether each individual test should be reported during the run
  verbose: false,

  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest"
  },


};
```

**SetupTests.js**

```
/** Used in jest.config.js */
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import { Adapter  } from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

**Package.json**

```
 "devDependencies": {

  "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
"enzyme": "^3.3.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"jest": "^23.4.2"
 }
```

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, I did switch the library instead